# Google Apps Script: How to update range on several slicers at once?

Tags: google-apps-script

Problem: Cannot update the ranges for two or more slicers with Google Script

Info: The sheet contains two slicers

Code:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Tracking');

  var slicers = sheet.getSlicers();
  var slicerRange = sheet.getRange('A3:A160'); //current slicer range A3:A165

  slicers[0,1].setRange(slicerRange);
}

Error: Two slicers can either have zero or all common rows.
```

What is wrong? The code works if I only work with one slicer in the sheet and code.

Thanks so much in advance for any help!

Comment: I don't use slicers much but it looks to me that getSlicers() returns a flat array  so what is this syntax `slicers[0,1]` supposed to do?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The setRange function required that I pointed to the single elements in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think you can edit their range.
But you could probably remove and create them again with your new range:

```
function test(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Tracking');

  var slicers = sheet.getSlicers();
  var newRange = sheet.getRange('A3:A160'); // your new range

  var slicersCount = 0;

  for (i=0;i<slicers.length;i++){
    slicers[i].remove();
    slicersCount ++;
  }

  for (i=0;i<slicersCount;i++){
    sheet.insertSlicer(newRange, 5, 3); // choose anchorRowPos and anchorColPos you want
  }

}
```

And then you can modify the rest of their settings as you wish.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your help! It eventually helped me to make it work.

This is the code I ended up with, which is without counter on the insertSlicer() since I need to give individual settings:

```
function test() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Tracking');



  var slicers = sheet.getSlicers();
  var rowValue = sheet.getLastRow();
  var newRange = sheet.getRange('A3:X'+rowValue); //new range

  for (i=0; i<slicers.length; i++){
    slicers[i].remove();
  }

  //Slicers to column A and D
  destinationSheet.insertSlicer(newRange, 2, 1); // choose anchorRowPos and anchorColPos
  destinationSheet.insertSlicer(newRange, 2, 4); 


  //Get new slicers
  var slicers = destinationSheet.getSlicers();

  var filterCriteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().setHiddenValues(['']).build();
  slicers[0].setColumnFilterCriteria(1, filterCriteria);
  slicers[0].setTitle('Title1');

  var filterCriteria2 = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().setHiddenValues(['1']).build();
  slicers[1].setColumnFilterCriteria(24, filterCriteria2);
  slicers[1].setTitle('Title2');
}
```