# Google Script for updating Slicer ranges

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a problem in updating the ranges in multiple slicers at once, which is not possible.
I tried using the script below that i found in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66357977/google-apps-script-how-to-update-range-on-several-slicers-at-once#new-answer?newreg=63fcaac915e249148dea834eaa2a1f17) for automatically deleting and recreating the slicers with the desired range.
but i get the following error. "destinationSheet" not defined.

Would appreciate in you can help me with a solution here.

Thank you.

```
function test() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Tracking');



  var slicers = sheet.getSlicers();
  var rowValue = sheet.getLastRow();
  var newRange = sheet.getRange('A3:X'+rowValue); //new range

  for (i=0; i<slicers.length; i++){
    slicers[i].remove();
  }

  //Slicers to column A and D
  destinationSheet.insertSlicer(newRange, 2, 1); // choose anchorRowPos and anchorColPos
  destinationSheet.insertSlicer(newRange, 2, 4); 


  //Get new slicers
  var slicers = destinationSheet.getSlicers();

  var filterCriteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().setHiddenValues(['']).build();
  slicers[0].setColumnFilterCriteria(1, filterCriteria);
  slicers[0].setTitle('Title1');

  var filterCriteria2 = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().setHiddenValues(['1']).build();
  slicers[1].setColumnFilterCriteria(24, filterCriteria2);
  slicers[1].setTitle('Title2');
}
```

Comment: I think that the error message of `i get the following error. "destinationSheet" not defined` shows the current issue of your script. In your script, the variable of `destinationSheet is not declared. So please declare it. Or, do you want to use `sheet` as `destinationSheet`? If it's so, how about modifying `destinationSheet` to `sheet`? But I'm not sure about your actual goal. So if this was not the direct solution to your issue, I apologize.

Comment: Hello,Thank you for your comment. I tried also to change it to "Sheet"  but i get the same error. "Sheet' Not defined. I just copied the code and adjusted it for my workbook. I am not verry good at this. I guess the goal is to delete the current slicers and create new ones with defined range and filtered criterias.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. In your goal, you want to use `sheet` as `destinationSheet`? If it's so, `Sheet` is not declared in your script. In your script, `sheet` is used. How about this?

Comment: Using "sheet" instead of "Sheet" worked like charm. I didn't know this was case sensitive. :). Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Tanaike's suggestion to change the "destinationSheet" part of the code to 'sheet', the code writen as below worked.

```
function test() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Tracking');



  var slicers = sheet.getSlicers();
  var rowValue = sheet.getLastRow();
  var newRange = sheet.getRange('A3:X'); //new range

  for (i=0; i<slicers.length; i++){
    slicers[i].remove();
  }

  //Slicers to column A and D
  sheet.insertSlicer(newRange, 2, 1); // choose anchorRowPos and anchorColPos
  sheet.insertSlicer(newRange, 2, 4); 


  //Get new slicers
  var slicers = sheet.getSlicers();

  var filterCriteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().setHiddenValues(['']).build();
  slicers[0].setColumnFilterCriteria(1, filterCriteria);
  slicers[0].setTitle('Title1');

  var filterCriteria2 = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().setHiddenValues(['1']).build();
  slicers[1].setColumnFilterCriteria(24, filterCriteria2);
  slicers[1].setTitle('Title2');
}
```